# Where are the After Effects workspaces saved?

Tags: after-effects, adobe, video-production

Is there a way to import custom workspaces from another computer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According [to Adobe](https://helpx.adobe.com/in/after-effects/using/workspaces-panels-viewers.html#Customizingworkspaces):

Workspaces are stored in XML files in the preferences folder. With some caveats regarding monitor size and layout, these workspaces can be moved to another computer and used there.

Windows:

`[drive]:\Users\[user_name]\AppData\Roaming\Adobe\After Effects\[version]\ModifiedWorkspaces`

Mac OS:

`[drive]/Users/[user_name]/Library/Preferences/Adobe/After Effects/[version]/ModifiedWorkspaces`